# SQL Server - OPTION CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone tell me if the `OPTION` clause is available in SQL Server 2012.

I cannot see any documentation to see when it was introduced.

I want to use `OPTION (LOOP JOIN)` on a SQL Server 2012 database...

Thanks

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=347

Comment: Join hints have been part of SQL Server since at least SQL Server 2005 -- and probably earlier, but my local docs don't go back that far. The current online documentation is unfortunately useless if you want to know when a feature was introduced -- supposedly they're working on that.

Comment: Why do you need to use a join hint? There are rarely times that any query hints are a good idea. You are effectively telling sql server that you know a better approach to retrieving the data than the query engine. They should be a last resort when everything else has been exhausted.

Comment: Can anyone tell me the earliest version this is a available on ? We are adding this to stored procedure and we have some very old versions...

Comment: If you have actual versions earlier than SQL Server 2005, you shouldn worry about whether join hints are supported -- you should be investing into upgrading, because the improvements in the optimizer may well mean you don't even need any hints to begin with (and when you do, there are more options available). If you have nothing earlier than SQL Server 2005, you can trivially verify these are supported by [downloading Books Online for 2005 for yourself](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=4152); it's still available. Note that even BOL 2005 recommends against their use.

Comment: Last but not least, when you are considering *any* kind of hint or runtime tweak that's supposed to improve performance, you should be in a position to actually test it and revert it if it doesn't help. Merely knowing whether it's supported will not tell you if the hint has the desired effect across database instances, because query performance depends on more than that (the optimizer itself, index and statistics maintenance, actual data in tables). If you are not in such a position, move towards that rather than ticking "supported on" checkboxes.

Answer (score 3):

As [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) stated, yes - the option (loop join) is available in SQL 2012.

I spun up a new SQL Database in Azure, changed the compatibility level to 110 (SQL 2012), and ran two queries. Screen shot of both execution plans shown as well.

```
select * from saleslt.customer c
inner join SalesLT.CustomerAddress ca
    on c.CustomerID = ca.CustomerID

select * from saleslt.customer c
inner join SalesLT.CustomerAddress ca
    on c.CustomerID = ca.CustomerID
OPTION (LOOP JOIN);
```

[image: Loop Join Execution Plan]

As stated by others, I also usually don't force hints but answering your question as stated: Yes, it is available.

Comment: Compatibility level cannot be used as a (reliable) way to ascertain a feature is supported in an earlier version. If the syntax is rejected, this does show that the feature is almost certainly not supported, but if it is accepted this still doesn't prove much, because the compat level specifically aims only to preserve backwards compatibility with queries that might have parsed differently in earlier versions. For example, `TRUNCATE TABLE WITH (PARTITIONS (..))` is a feature introduced in SQL Server 2016, but this syntax will still be accepted in a database with compat level 110.

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone tell me if the `OPTION` clause is available in SQL Server
>   2012.
>
> I cannot see any documentation to see when it was introduced.

Yes it is available in SQL Server 2012. The `OPTION` clause goes back to at least [SQL Server 7.0](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CWf1Pv6OeAcC&lpg=PA761&ots=82-1wfOv7-&dq=sql%20server%20%226.5%22%20query%20hint&pg=PA762#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> I want to use `OPTION (LOOP JOIN)` on a SQL Server 2012 database...

The availability of the `OPTION` clause does not mean that `OPTION (LOOP JOIN)` is available. These have been added to over various product versions.

Below is the BOL entry on hints for SQL Server 2000

[image: enter link description here]

In 2000 the only way of specifying join algorithms is at the individual join level (which also fixes the join order).

By 2005 BOL documents the following more extensive selection of query hints so `OPTION (LOOP JOIN)` is available from that version.

```
<query_hint > ::= 
{ { HASH | ORDER } GROUP 
  | { CONCAT | HASH | MERGE } UNION 
  | { LOOP | MERGE | HASH } JOIN 
  | FAST number_rows 
  | FORCE ORDER 
  | MAXDOP number_of_processors 
  | OPTIMIZE FOR ( @variable_name = literal_constant [ , ...n ] ) 
  | PARAMETERIZATION { SIMPLE | FORCED }
  | RECOMPILE
  | ROBUST PLAN 
  | KEEP PLAN 
  | KEEPFIXED PLAN
  | EXPAND VIEWS 
  | MAXRECURSION number 
  | USE PLAN N'xml_plan'
}
```

Following that these  new hints were made available

- SQL Server 2008 introduced `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` and the `TABLE HINT` query hint
- SQL Server 2012 introduced `IGNORE_NONCLUSTERED_COLUMNSTORE_INDEX`
- SQL Server 2016 SP1

  - `{ FORCE | DISABLE } EXTERNALPUSHDOWN` (Polybase)
  - `MAX_GRANT_PERCENT = percent`
  - `MIN_GRANT_PERCENT = percent`
  - `NO_PERFORMANCE_SPOOL`
  - `USE HINT ( '<hint_name>' [ , ...n ] )`
- SQL Server 2019 `{ FORCE | DISABLE } SCALEOUTEXECUTION` (BDC)

Also at some point `QUERYTRACEON trace_flag` was introduced - not sure when as I think it was available before being documented

Comment: `QUERYTRACEON` was introduced in [SQL Server 2005 SP2](https://support.microsoft.com/help/2801413/) (assuming that article is correct, but there's no reason to doubt it). It was not retroactively added to Books Online for 2005, though; determining when it made its debut in the full docs is probably more trouble than it's worth. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Is available on all versions as long as I remember.

But as you need to state on what join you want to do the loop. You are setting incorrectly the hint:

```
select * from saleslt.customer c
inner join SalesLT.CustomerAddress ca
    on c.CustomerID = ca.CustomerID
```

The force nested loop should be:

```
select * from saleslt.customer c
inner LOOP join SalesLT.CustomerAddress ca
    on c.CustomerID = ca.CustomerID
```

You can also try to force MERGE and HASH joins. Anyway I **encourage against those practices, and instead properly code the sqls so the optimizer is able to find out the right way to do the JOIN**. An Increase on table data may set a Nested Loop as a bad execution plan, and you will be forcing it. Ensure the SQL, index design and statistics are ok, and you wont need those hints.

Cheers,